# Calling individual columns that have been resampled and aggregated from a larger dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, resampling

I have a large dataframe and in order to gather some stats for a figure, I have resampled the data for each 6 hour period and then aggregated that data by mean number and count.

Code for doing this.

```
meantime = df.set_index('datetime').resample('6h').agg(['mean', 'count'])

print(meantime['l16'])
```

Notice I only resample one column (l16) of the dataframe, this is all I want.

The results:

```
                          mean  count
datetime                             
2019-02-03 00:00:00   1.322222      9
2019-02-03 06:00:00   5.733333     12
2019-02-03 12:00:00   6.258333     12
2019-02-03 18:00:00   2.325000     12
```

I would like to do two things with this.

1. Get rid of any resampled row with a count of less than 6.
2. Isolate the mean column, and turn that into a list for eventual plotting as an overlay on the plot.

The problem I'm running into is simply how to do each of these parts. I'm not sure how to write the code to do this.

I've attempted to this by writing something like this, but I don't know how to isolate the resampled column from the dataframe column.

```
invalid = meantime['l16' *count?* ] < 6
print(meantime['l16' *mean?*]
```

I've looked around and can't seem to find my question answered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Isolate any resampled row with a count of less than 6.

   `invalid = meantime.loc[meantime['count'] < 6]`
2. Isolate the mean column, and turn that into a list for eventual
   plotting as an overlay on the plot.

   `meanvalues = meantime['mean'].to_list()`

Comment: I get a type error: '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'

Comment: @user279955 Updated my answer

Comment: Got it to work by using meantime.loc[meantime['l16']['count'] < 6]

Comment: meantime['l16']['count'] is what i was looking for in how to write the code to get the elements of that part of the dataframe. found elsewhere, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to receive 6 resamples of data, then you should use a for loop, like so:

```
x = 1
while True:
    print "To infinity and beyond! We're getting close, on %d now!" % (x)
    x += 1
```